# Can I override Ext.define?

Tags: extjs

I want to override the default namespace which is Ext.Define. How can I do that? I want some thing like this **Abc.define** instead of **Ext.Define**.

Thank you in advance.
Cheers!!

Comment: Do you want something like an alias for "Ext"?

Answer (score 2):

You can reference Ext in another variable if you must.

```
Abc = Ext;

Abc.define(....
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to though. If your real intention is to have your created objects to be in a custom namespace - this is what Ext.define does.

```
Ext.define("Abc.model.Website", {....
```